# Can not POST special characters via NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsurlconnection

This is my code:

```
NSURL *s =[self getAbsoluteURL:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *requestURL = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:s cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120.00];
[requestURL setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSLog(@"%@",parameter);
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
if ([parameter isKindOfClass : [NSString class]]) {
   [requestURL setHTTPBody:[parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
}

NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSError *error1;
NSData *apiData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestURL returningResponse:&response error:&error1];
```

It works fine but when I post some special characters like '&' it sends nothing to the server, it post a blank data.

Case:
Actual parameter: "&&&"
Posted : ""

Can anyone give me a clue how to resolve this?

Comment: Just tested your code with iPhone Simulator, and it works just fine. Raw posted data is "&&&" (3 bytes), as specified in parameter. If your server side expects a form, it will be empty of course, because there's no actual data posted, just delimiters.

Comment: try replacing & with %26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to post the data by URL Encoding. For Encoding I used this:

```
-(NSString *)encodeData : (NSString *)string {
    return (NSString *)
    CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                            (CFStringRef) string,
                                            NULL,
                                            (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}
```

Now datas are posted as I wanted. :)